# In chart.js bar chart, how do I label each bar within a category?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How do I label each bar within a category for the chart.js bar chart?

I have 1 category, with 2 bars within that category. I'm using gradients on the bar chart and these can only be applied to bars within a single category.

```
options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    callback: (value, index, values) => {
                        console.log(value, index, values);
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
}

let ctx = this.bar.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

    let grad1 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
    grad1.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(105,130,231)');
    grad1.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(125,222,238)');

    let grad2 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
    grad2.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(233,105,210)');
    grad2.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(247,126,151)');

    this.barColors.push({backgroundColor: grad1, hoverBackgroundColor: grad1});
    this.barColors.push({backgroundColor: grad2, hoverBackgroundColor: grad2});
```

HTML:

```
<canvas #bar baseChart
        [datasets]="plotData"
        [labels]="l"
        [options]="options"
        chartType="bar"
        [colors]="barColors"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</canvas>
```

Comment: it's angular. but i will include.

Comment: labels "l" is just an array containing 1 string..

Comment: I tried that but the gradients don't change between each bar.
I have 2 gradients, therefore I need plotData to contain 2 objects..

Comment: dude please test your solutions before posting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) set 2 labels for each sub category within a category
2) for each bar within a category, add the value if it matches the label position, then add 0 to the value for the alternative sub category not matching the label position

This will produce a bar chart where each category only has 1 bar of a colour gradient unique to that subcategory.

You may need to play around with the bar sizing, since I only have 2 sub categories, I set

```
scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 8,
            categoryPercentage: 0.1
        }]
    }
}
```

and it aligned with the category label closely enough for me.